# Cannot find emacs.app on M1 Mac with homebrew

Tags: osx, install

I recently installed emacs on a M1 Mac. I have done this before on my previous M1 mac with brew:

`brew install emacs`

Usually, I would find the emacs.app file in the `/opt/homebrew/Celler/emacs` folder. And them I would move it or link it to applications.

However, the application is not there?

brew says it's up to date. Am I missing something?

Comment: This appears to be a question about brew, not emacs. Perhaps there is a better place you could ask it, one that answers questions about brew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the installation process is slightly different on Monteray, I used `brew install --cask emacs` and it worked.